# Non-locking TextWriterTraceListener?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I'm using `TextWriterTraceListener` to ouptput my trace information to a log file. Unfortunately it locks the logfile and I am not able to open it externally while the application is running. Any way to make this possible?

Comment: NLog uses optimistic file locking strategy by default in all of its file appenders (it's name for TraceListener, which it inherited from log4net, and earlier from log4j).  One could harvest that code from NLog or log4net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what constructor you used.  The TextWriterTraceListener(String) constructor creates a StreamWriter that opens the file with FileShare.Read.  That allows any process to read the file.

The usual problem is trying to open the file with the wrong FileShare setting in the other process.  You have to specify FileShare.ReadWrite.  The trace listener has already gained write access to the file, you cannot deny it.

Comment: Dotpeek might be getting it wrong, but its EnsureWriter does this: `this.writer = (TextWriter) new StreamWriter(path, true, encodingWithFallback, 4096);` (e.g. a file lock)

Comment: This sounds great, but it would have been nice if you would have added "how" to specify FileShare.ReadWrite. I have found other posts that say it is not possible to change the default FileShare.Read. I have tried creating  FileStream with configurations, but the TextWriterTraceListener is no longer writing to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can monitor the file externally or not when using `TextWriterTraceListener` depends a bit on what software you use for monitoring it. I usually use [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) that has no issues with the file being locked.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote one very recently.  Unfortunately I'm not able to share the source code BUT I can tell you that there's less than 500 lines of code.  The key is opening the file correctly, allowing read sharing as you've noted.  The other thing I did was buffered the writes and only wrote them after I received a set number of bytes.  I also wrote asynchronously so it didn't block the application.